# is it possible to run a VM on 64 bit host imported from a 32 bits host?

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, 32-bit, virtualization

1. **Goal**:  [Export and import](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf) an Ubuntu VM
2. **Original System**: -Host machine (Windows 7 32 bits)  -Virtualization sysem (VirtualBox)
3. **New System**: -Host machine (Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bits)  -Virtualization sysem (VirtualBox)
4. **Question**: Could the VM run on a 64 bits host  when moving it from a 32 bits host ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run the VM on a 64-bit Ubuntu, as Virtualbox emulates most of the hardware inside the VM, and it shouldn't matter much on what the host OS is.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you think I can import that VM produced on VirtualBox to a VmMWare player instead ? I ask this because I guessed there is no VirtualBox that fits Ubuntu 11.04 (but i succeed to do it on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 or 14.04? If the latter, use `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` to install Virtualbox 4.3.10 or see [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) for the latest version (currently 4.3.14). Ubuntu 11.04 is EOL (end-of-life) and support ended almost 2 years ago.